# TypeError: name is null when trying to replace problematic characters

Tags: javascript, typeerror, isnull

In trying to remove problematic characters from imported text via JavaScript, I receive the TypeError: Name is "null"  on this line:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
```

Here is the relevant section of code -

```
fixNameToMiniCharset : function (name) {
    if(typeof name == 'undefined') {
        com.synckolab.global.consoleService.logStringMessage("undefined string " + new Error("s").stack);
    }
    var ret = "";
    // avoid double placeholders 
    var placeHolder = false;
    for ( var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
        switch (name.charAt(i)) {
        // character replaces... better this way
        case '\u00e4':
        case '\u00e1':
        case '\u00e0':
        case '\u00e2':
        case '\u00e3':
        case '\u00e5':
        case '\u00e6':
            placeHolder = false;
            ret += 'a';
            break;
        case '\u00c4':
        case '\u00c1':
        case '\u00c0':
        case '\u00c2':
        case '\u00c3':
        case '\u00c5':
        case '\u00c6':
            placeHolder = false;
            ret += 'A';
            break;
        case '\u00f6':
        case '\u00f3':
        case '\u00f2':
        case '\u00f4':
        case '\u00f5':
        case '\u00f8':
            placeHolder = false;
            ret += 'o';
            break;
        case '\u00d6':
        case '\u00d3':
        case '\u00d2':
        case '\u00d4':
        case '\u00d5':
        case '\u00D6':
            placeHolder = false;
            ret += 'O';
            break;
        case '\u00fc':
        case '\u00fa':
        case '\u00f9':
        case '\u00fb':
        case '\u0169':
        case '\u0171':
            placeHolder = false;
            ret += 'u';
            break;
        case '\u00dc':
        case '\u00da':
        case '\u00d9':
        case '\u00db':
        case '\u0168':
            placeHolder = false;
            ret += 'U';
            break;
        case '\u00c8':
        case '\u00c9':
        case '\u00ca':
        case '\u00cb':
            placeHolder = false;
            ret += 'E';
            break;
        case '\u00e8':
        case '\u00e9':
        case '\u00ea':
        case '\u00eb':
            placeHolder = false;
            ret += 'e';
            break;
        case '\u00ec':
        case '\u00ed':
        case '\u00ee':
        case '\u00ef':
            placeHolder = false;
            ret += 'i';
            break;
        case '\u00dd':
        case '\u00a5':
            placeHolder = false;
            ret += 'Y';
            break;
        case '\u00c7':
            placeHolder = false;
            ret += 'C';
            break;
        case '\u00e7':
            placeHolder = false;
            ret += 'c';
            break;
        case '\u00fd':
        case '\u00ff':
            placeHolder = false;
            ret += 'y';
            break;
        case '\u00df':
            placeHolder = false;
            ret += 's';
            break;
        case '\u00f1':
            placeHolder = false;
            ret += 'n';
            break;
        case '\u00b2':
            placeHolder = false;
            ret += '2';
            break;
        case '\u00b3':
            placeHolder = false;
            ret += '3';
            break;

        // chars which are no problem just stay
        case '_':
            // make sure to print it only once
            if(!placeHolder) {
                ret += name.charAt(i);
                placeHolder = true;
            }
            break;

        default:
            var c = name.charAt(i);
            if ((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= '0' && c <= '9')) {
                placeHolder = false;
                ret += c;
            } else {
                if (!placeHolder) {
                    ret += '_';
                    placeHolder = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is quite simple, at first glance: you're checking the argument's type: if it's undefined your function won't run. But in JS null isn't undefined and undefined isn't null.

```
console.log(typeof null);//object!
console.log(null == undefined);//true
console.log(null === undefined);//false!
```

So either replace your if (`if(typeof name == 'undefined')`) by a check on all falsy values:

```
if(!name)
{
    //invalid argument: false, null, 0, '' and undefined
}
//valid args: true, '0', any number, other than 0, strings objects...
```

Or, perhaps preferable in your case: check if you've got a length property to play with

```
if (!name || !name.length)
{
    //invalid
}
```

*OR* check to see if the input is a string:

```
if (typeof name === 'string')
```

Comment: I should have mentioned, I originally used    if(!name) with the same results

Comment: Of course, if an object is passed, that doesn't have a length property you'll get an error: an object is not a falsy value, but that doesn't mean there's a length property. That's why I suggested checking `!name || !name.length` <-- falsy value or value that doesn't have a length property. BTW: I've noticed you're yet to accept an answer. If you don't except answers, people tend to not bother answering your questions after a while... just a friendly word of advise :P

Comment: Thank you. I failed to notice the gigantic checkmark! Your fix mostly works - I think I am running into other trouble elsewhere.  What this is for is a thunderbird plugin to sync contacts. I can get things to work fine with your fix if I do not use the default contacts folder. With the default folder (which should work), I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @user1514992: just try to `console.log(name);` and `console.log(arguments)`, to see what parameters are actually passed. The second (arguments) is an object containing all parameters that are passed, even those you didn't specify. perhaps there's a few things going on there, too

Comment: Here's the console output just before the error:`23649 - File not readable: [xpconnect wrapped nsIFile]` then `undefined string @chrome://synckolab/content/tools/text.js:77
@chrome://synckolab/content/addressbookTools.js:269
@chrome://synckolab/content/addressbookTools.js:1679
@chrome://synckolab/content/addressbookTools.js:590
@chrome://synckolab/content/addressbookTools.js:1739
@chrome://synckolab/content/addressbook.js:635
@chrome://synckolab/content/synckolab.js:984
@chrome://synckolab/content/synckolab.js:804
@chrome://synckolab/content/synckolab.js:1041
`then, `TypeError: name is null`

Comment: @user1514992: Well, that doesn't really say much, except for the fact that the source of the problem lies elsewhere: how doe you call this function, what do you pass as a parameter? It seems to me like you're trying to read a file that is either not accessible, or you're passing some sort of pointer(?) Are you using an apple API?

Comment: The source can be found here: [link](http://www.gargan.org/en/Mozilla_Extensions/SyncKolab/CVS_Nightly/). It is a thunderbird plugin that is supposed to sync contacts & calendars, but it hangs when syncing distribution lists previously created in roundcube. Just trying to find the issue in thousands of lines of unfamiliar territory!

Comment: @user1514992: the issue is caused by the code at line 70 of addressbookTools.js: from your stacktrace you can see that line 269 gets executed, passes the return value of `getCardProperty` to the `fixNameToMiniCharset`, but line 70 says: `if (card[prop]) // TODO better check for undefined?`, change that to `if (card.hasOwnProperty(prop))` and see how that works out. Other than that, there's nothing to do but go back over the stack trace, line by line to see how the `fixNameToMiniCharset` method is called

Comment: Getting closer, However, New errors pop up - line 861 of tools.js
`function id = id.replace is not a function` where the relevant surrounding code is `com.synckolab.tools.logMessage("syncDbFile:  (" +com.synckolab.tools.text.fixNameToMiniCharset(config.serverKey) + "/" + config.type + "_" + config.name + "/" + id + ")", com.synckolab.global.LOG_ERROR);
  
  id = id.replace(/[ :.;$\\\/]\#\@/g, "_");` Two steps forward, one step back.

Answer (score 0):

Change these lines:

```
if(typeof name == 'undefined') {
    com.synckolab.global.consoleService.logStringMessage("undefined string " + new Error("s").stack);
}
```

to the following:

```
if(!name) {
    com.synckolab.global.consoleService.logStringMessage("undefined string " + new Error("s").stack);
    return;
}
```

This will check for empty undefined and other falsy values which will stop your function from working.

Comment: This does allow objects, which needn't have a length property